# Github API personal access tokens throws Unauthorized error

Tags: api, web-services, github, pagination, token

I've created a personal access token on github, it works when I use it like this:

```
https://api.github.com/users/xyz/repos?access_token=TOKEN
```

But it throws `Unauthorized` error when I try using [Pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) like this:

```
https://api.github.com/users/xyz/repos?access_token=TOKEN?page=1&per_page=10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and replace the second `?` by `&`:

```
https://api.github.com/users/xyz/repos?access_token=TOKEN&page=1&per_page=10
                                                       ^^^^^
```

That should allow you to *chain* URL parameters.